# Constructing a homomorphism using the universal property of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $R\subset\mathbb{C}[t]$ be the set of polynomials whose first derivative vanishes at $0$. Using the universal properties of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras and of quotient rings, construct a surjective $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism
$\phi :\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2-y^3) \rightarrow R$.

I realise that this shouldn't be a difficult question as the homomorphism should basically be given by the universal property and then I would just need to prove that it's surjective, however it isn't clear to me and I'm a little confused about what the homomorphism is. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If you figure out $R=\mathbb C[t^2,t^3]$, everything else should be trivial.

Comment: Thank you @MooS that's helped a lot!